# Polylang - Remove slug of homepage in secondary language

Tags: plugin-polylang

I have a website with polylang and can't seem to figure out how to remove the slug in the homepage of any language that is not the same one.

For instance, I have example.com but in english its example.com/en/home.

Is there a way to keep it at /en/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. For a more comprehensive answer, see: https://polylang.pro/doc/define-your-home-page-as-a-static-page/

Answer (score 5):

Well, I'm a moron. It's under Settings->URL Modifications... the 'The front page url contains the language code instead of the page name or page id' checkbox.